# Getting "not all code paths return a value" for code that will never not return a value

Tags: c#

The method I write doesn't return a value though I write every possible conditions to return a value.

What I understand is  whenever the compiler sees the return keyword it'll stop, execute the program and return the value next to the return keyword. Even if it is in the loop it'll break the loop and return the value but it the compiler shows the "**not all code paths return a value**" error. And there's an else conditions for the other possible conditions and how comes the error show up.

**So, how the return keyword actually work?**

I am so confused.

```
using System;

public static class PhoneNumber
{
  public static (bool IsNewYork, bool IsFake, string LocalNumber) Analyze(string phoneNumber)
  {
     bool flag = true;
     string[] numSub = phoneNumber.Split("-");
     while(flag)
        {
            if(numSub[0] == "212")
            {
                if(numSub[1] == "555")
                {
                    return (true, true, numSub[2]);
                }
                else{return (true, false, numSub[2]);}
            } // end of if condition

            else{
                if(numSub[1] == "555")
                    {
                        return (false, true, numSub[2]);
                    }
                else{return (false, false, numSub[2]);}
                } // end of the else condition
         } // end of the loop
    
    }
```

Comment: I think you get this issue because there is no default return statement at the end. All the if/else may work and cover everything but as far as the compiler is concerned there should still be a default return statement at the end. Outside the if / else logic. And loop.

Comment: You don't return anything outside your `while` loop, even though your logic indicates you will never leave the loop.

Comment: The compiler can't see that it's an infinite loop. It won't present the error if you have `while (true)`

Comment: What is the point of the while loop in your code?

Comment: All of the code following splitting up the phone # can be replaced by a single return statement.  Try to rewrite it that way.

Comment: Le's just imagine for a moment, that a solar flare hits your computer and magically changes `flag = false` in memory at the exact same moment that C# is busy doing the Split. What happens then, if the `flag` is false, and the loop never runs? What do you want C# to do?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm really appreciated it. I've got the answer and clearly understand how it works.

Comment: @Lycan You did not answer my question, and it's really the crux of the problem here: what is the purpose of the while loop in your code?

Answer (score 2):

> not all code paths return a value

The compiler is not "smart" enough to know that you will enter the `while` loop.  So it sees the code path that doesn't enter the `while` loop as a possible code path without a `return`.

As-written the code structure doesn't make much sense, so it should probably be restructured to make the compiler happy, and be easier to read and maintain.  You can also just a thrown exception after the `while` to get rid of the compilation error.

Comment: Adding an exception there would satisfy the compiler...but that's hardly the best fix for a situation like this.

Comment: I'm assuming there's some real reason for that code structure, and the question is simplified.

Comment: More specifically it's because the condition that determines whether or not the loop will run is a variable. If you set it to `while(true)`, the compiler is fine with it. The fact that it's in a variable indicates to the compiler it may not be the same between when it's declared and when it's evaluated.

Comment: I don't think you should assume anything about this code. There's no need for an infinite loop to accomplish this. The proper solution would be to ditch the loop. We've got to answer questions based on what we're presented, not what we *think* they might actually have. Adding an exception to code that will never ever be reached isn't a good solution, just a hack. We should advocate for the correct code structure.

Comment: Fair enough, but this isn't https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Of course it's not. That doesn't mean we should advocate for low quality code in an attempt to satisfy the compiler.

Comment: Thanks everyone!!! I've got an answer. I clearly understand how that's work.